# ssrs 2008 r2,select 1 or more value or none of the above

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In an an existing SSRS 2008 r2 report, I want to have a parameter called @hair where the user

```
can see if the customer purchased one of the following items:
 1. hair spray,
 2. hair shampoo,
 3. Hair color,
 4. hair conditioner, or
 5. No hair product purchased.

The table is called inventory and the values for the field called hairproduct are
 1. hair spray = 'HR',
 2. hair shampoo = 'HS',
 3. hair color = 'HC',
 4. Hair conditionier = 'HD',
 5. If hair product is not purchased hairproduct value is null.
```

This is due to
    the inventory table contains columns like hairproduct, eyeproduct, faceproduct. If a
    particular product is purchased, the column will contain a value. If a customer purchases
    all 4 hair products and 3 eyeproducts, and 9 faceproducts, the inventory table will contain
    16 columns for a particualr customer.

In the parameter window, I can use the following to have the correct values be displayed in the
selection window:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IsNull(inventory.hairproduct,'') as hairid,
CASE IsNull(inventory.hairproduct,'')
WHEN 'HR' then 'hair spray'
WHEN 'HS' then 'hair shampoo'
WHEN 'HC' then 'Hair color'
WHEN 'HC' then 'hair conditioner'
WHEN '' then 'No hair product purchased'
FROM Inventory
```

**Note the @hairproduct parameter allows blank values and allows multiple values.

However in the main query for the ssrs 2008 r2 report, I am not certain how I would change the following 
statement to select 'No hair product purchased'.

The current select statement looks like the following:

```
select customer_id,hairproduct
from inventory where customer_id = @customerid 
hairproduct in (@hairproduct)
```

.

Basically I need to change the main query, dataset that matches the parameter @hairproduct, or possibly add
a new parameter that means 'No hair product purchased' to report on the customer that has one or more hair products
purchased or none.

Thus can you tell me and/or show me sql that will solve my problem?

Comment: Do you not have a table where you have all these product names stored rather than using this long case statement to pick the product names you can simple use that table to populate your drop down for Products parameter and in parameter properties pick the values to be displayed in your drop down.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select
    customer_id,
    isnull(hairproduct,'No hair product purchased') as hairproduct
from inventory
where
    customer_id = @customerid 
    and isnull(hairproduct,'No hair product purchased') in (@hairproduct)
```

Comment: can you explain your answer. how will this select records when there are no products and when several hair products can be selected? Do I need to modify the dataset that is used for the parameter drop down list for the user to select?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your Selection query. If you select the `'No hair product purchased'` option, it will now be matched with every `NULL` hairproduct value.